# Spark, ML, StringIndexer: handling unseen labels

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-ml

My goal is to build a multicalss classifier.

I have built a pipeline for feature extraction and it includes as a first step a StringIndexer transformer to map each class name to a label, this label will be used in the classifier training step.

The pipeline is fitted the training set.

The test set has to be processed by the fitted pipeline in order to extract the same feature vectors.

Knowing that my test set files have the same structure of the training set. The possible scenario here is to face an unseen class name in the test set, in that case the StringIndexer will fail to find the label, and an exception will be raised.

Is there a solution for this case? or how can we avoid that from happening?

Comment: Please re-accept the answer by @queise. It's far better than the one already added as a solution.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

With Spark 2.2 (released 7-2017) you are able to use the `.setHandleInvalid("keep")` option when creating the indexer. With this option, the indexer adds new indexes when it sees new labels.

```
val categoryIndexerModel = new StringIndexer()
  .setInputCol("category")
  .setOutputCol("indexedCategory")
  .setHandleInvalid("keep") // options are "keep", "error" or "skip"
```

From the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#stringindexer): there are three strategies regarding how StringIndexer will handle unseen labels when you have fit a StringIndexer on one dataset and then use it to transform another:

- 'error': throws an exception (which is the default)
- 'skip': skips the rows containing the unseen labels entirely (removes the rows on the output!)
- 'keep': puts unseen labels in a special additional bucket, at index numLabels

Please see the linked documentation for examples on how the output of StringIndexer looks for the different options.

Comment: Can you provide some more detail on the exact differences between `keep` `error` `skip` options. `Skip`, removes the datapoint? `Error`, interrupts the model? and `Keep`, adds a new column? Does this work for both ways, so unseen values in test, not in train, and unseen values in train not in test?

Answer (score 15):

There's a way around this in Spark 1.6.

Here's the jira:  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-8764

Here's an example:

```
val categoryIndexerModel = new StringIndexer()
  .setInputCol("category")
  .setOutputCol("indexedCategory")
  .setHandleInvalid("skip") // new method.  values are "error" or "skip"
```

I started using this, but ended up going back to KrisP's 2nd bullet point about fitting this particular Estimator to the full dataset.

You'll need this later in the pipeline when you convert the IndexToString.

Here's the modified example:

```
val categoryIndexerModel = new StringIndexer()
  .setInputCol("category")
  .setOutputCol("indexedCategory")
  .fit(itemsDF) // Fit the Estimator and create a Model (Transformer)

... do some kind of classification ...

val categoryReverseIndexer = new IndexToString()
  .setInputCol(classifier.getPredictionCol)
  .setOutputCol("predictedCategory")
  .setLabels(categoryIndexerModel.labels) // Use the labels from the Model
```

Comment: But what happens when you try to apply the model to new data? You may find that there are new values in some columns that were not in the original test or training data. I'm afraid that setHandleInvalid("skip") will cause the whole row to be discarded, when you really just want to ignore the previously unseen value, but still use the other values in the row.

Comment: this would mean that the new unseen-before data does not belong to the same statistical distribution as the training data. It is OK, and in fact desirable in probably most applications to NOT give it a label since it does not "look" like any data the model has seen before. "Look like" in the statistical sense, obviously were trying to do Learning NOT Memorizing.

Comment: There is a new .setHandleInvalid("keep") option coming with Spark 2.2., that will add new indexes when dealing with new data. In my opinion this feature will be very useful, as hopefully a predictive model that you apply afterwards will output a valid prediction making use of all the other variables (of course the new indexes have zero predictive power).

Answer (score 11):

No nice way to do it, I'm afraid. Either

- filter out the test examples with unknown labels before applying `StringIndexer`
- or fit `StringIndexer` to the union of train and test dataframe, so you are assured all labels are there
- or transform the test example case with unknown label to a known label

Here is some sample code to perform above operations:

```
// get training labels from original train dataframe
val trainlabels = traindf.select(colname).distinct.map(_.getString(0)).collect  //Array[String]
// or get labels from a trained StringIndexer model
val trainlabels = simodel.labels 

// define an UDF on your dataframe that will be used for filtering
val filterudf = udf { label:String => trainlabels.contains(label)}

// filter out the bad examples 
val filteredTestdf = testdf.filter( filterudf(testdf(colname)))

// transform unknown value to some value, say "a"
val mapudf = udf { label:String => if (trainlabels.contains(label)) label else "a"}

// add a new column to testdf: 
val transformedTestdf = testdf.withColumn( "newcol", mapudf(testdf(colname)))
```

Comment: Isn't there a way to provide test data without any label at all so that the algorithm would predict it from scratch. In my case, I don't have labels for none of my test data items. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44127634/providing-test-data-items-with-empty-labels-in-spark-random-forest-classifier

In my case do I have to associate random labels for the items?

Comment: the answer from @queise using spark 2.2 is now the best answer

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was running spark ALS on a large data set and the data was not available at all partitions so I had to cache() the data appropriately and it worked like a charm

Answer (score 2):

To me, ignoring the rows completely by setting an argument (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-8764) is not really feasible way to solve the issue.

I ended up creating my own CustomStringIndexer transformer which will assign a new value for all new strings that were not encountered while training. You can also do this by changing the relevant portions of the spark feature code(just remove the if condition explicitly checking for this and make it return the length of the array instead) and recompile the jar.

Not really an easy fix, but it certainly is a fix.

I remember seeing a bug in JIRA to incorporate this as well: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-17498

It is set to be released with Spark 2.2 though. Just have to wait I guess :S