# org.apache.spark.SparkException: Unseen label with TrainValidationSplit

Tags: python, apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark

I was searching for this error but I haven't found anything related to `TrainValidationSplit`. So I wanna do parameter tuning and doing so with `TrainValidationSplit` gives the following error: `org.apache.spark.SparkException: Unseen label`.

I understand why this happens and increasing the `trainRatio` mitigates the problem but does not completely solve it.
For that matter, this is (part of) the code:

```
stages = []
for categoricalCol in categoricalCols:
    stringIndexer = StringIndexer(inputCol=categoricalCol, outputCol=categoricalCol+"Index")
    stages += [stringIndexer]

assemblerInputs = [x+"Index" for x in categoricalCols] + numericCols
assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=assemblerInputs, outputCol="features")
stages += [assembler]

labelIndexer = StringIndexer(inputCol='label', outputCol='indexedLabel')
stages += [labelIndexer]

dt = DecisionTreeClassifier(labelCol="indexedLabel", featuresCol="features")
stages += [dt]

evaluator = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator(labelCol='indexedLabel', predictionCol='prediction', metricName='f1')

paramGrid = (ParamGridBuilder()
             .addGrid(dt.maxDepth, [1,2,6])
             .addGrid(dt.maxBins, [20,40])
             .build())

pipeline = Pipeline(stages=stages)

trainValidationSplit = TrainValidationSplit(estimator=pipeline, estimatorParamMaps=paramGrid, evaluator=evaluator, trainRatio=0.95)

model = trainValidationSplit.fit(train_dataset)
train_dataset= model.transform(train_dataset)
```

I have seen this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35224675/spark-ml-stringindexer-throws-unseen-label-on-fit) but I am not sure whether it also applies to my case and I am wondering if there's a more appropriate solution.
Please, help?

Comment: Remember, you should split your data to train/test "before" doing feature normalization. Otherwise you will experience "Data Leakage".

Answer (score 2):

The `Unseen label` exception is usually associated with `StringIndexer`.

You split the data into training (95%) and validation (5%) dataset. I think there are some category values (in the `categoricalCol` columns) that appear in the training data but do not appear in the validation set.

Therefore, during the string indexing stage in the validation process, the `StringIndexer` sees an unseen label and throws that exception. By increasing the training ratio, you *increase the chance* that category values in the training set are a superset of that in the validation set, but this is only a workaround since there is no guarantee.

**One possible solution**: `fit` the `StringIndexer` with `train_dataset` first, and add the resulting `StringIndexerModel` to the pipeline stages. This way the `StringIndexer` would see all the possible category values.

```
for categoricalCol in categoricalCols:
    stringIndexer = StringIndexer(inputCol=categoricalCol, outputCol=categoricalCol+"Index")
    strIndexModel = stringIndexer.fit(train_dataset)
    stages += [strIndexModel]
```