# Error when passing data from a Dataframe into an existing ML VectorIndexerModel

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-ml

I have a Dataframe which I want to use for prediction with an existing model. I get an error when using the transform method of my model.

This is how I process the trainingdata.

```
forecast.printSchema()
```

The schema of my Dataframe:

```
root
 |-- PM10: double (nullable = false)
 |-- rain_3h: double (nullable = false)
 |-- is_rain: double (nullable = false)
 |-- wind_deg: double (nullable = false)
 |-- wind_speed: double (nullable = false)
 |-- humidity: double (nullable = false)
 |-- is_newYear: double (nullable = false)
 |-- season: double (nullable = false)
 |-- is_rushHour: double (nullable = false)
 |-- PM10_average: double (nullable = false)
```

Printing the first rows

```
forecast.show(5)
```

```
+----+-------+-------+--------+----------+--------+----------+------+-----------+------------+
|PM10|rain_3h|is_rain|wind_deg|wind_speed|humidity|is_newYear|season|is_rushHour|PM10_average|
+----+-------+-------+--------+----------+--------+----------+------+-----------+------------+
| 1.1|    1.0|    0.0| 15.0048|      7.27|     0.0|       0.0|   0.0|        0.0|         1.2|
| 1.1|    1.0|    0.0| 15.0048|      7.27|     0.0|       0.0|   0.0|        0.0|         1.2|
| 1.1|    1.0|    0.0| 15.0048|      7.27|     0.0|       0.0|   0.0|        0.0|         1.2|
| 1.1|    1.0|    0.0| 15.0048|      7.27|     0.0|       0.0|   0.0|        0.0|         1.2|
| 1.1|    1.0|    0.0| 15.0048|      7.27|     0.0|       0.0|   0.0|        0.0|         1.2|
+----+-------+-------+--------+----------+--------+----------+------+-----------+------------+
only showing top 5 rows
```

Preparing the features

```
assembler = VectorAssembler(
    inputCols=["rain_3h", "is_rain", "wind_deg", "wind_speed", "humidity", "is_newYear", "season", "is_rushHour", "PM10_average"],
outputCol="features")

output = assembler.transform(forecast)
output.registerTempTable("output")

features = spark.sql("SELECT features, PM10 as label FROM output")
features.printSchema()
```

```
+--------------------+-----+                                                    
|            features|label|
+--------------------+-----+
|(9,[0,2,3,8],[1.0...|  1.1|
|(9,[0,2,3,8],[1.0...|  1.1|
|(9,[0,2,3,8],[1.0...|  1.1|
|(9,[0,2,3,8],[1.0...|  1.1|
|(9,[0,2,3,8],[1.0...|  1.1|
+--------------------+-----+
only showing top 5 rows
```

And passing the data to the model

```
model = PipelineModel.load(path)

predict = model.transform(features)
predict.printSchema()
```

```
root
|-- features: vector (nullable = true)
|-- label: double (nullable = false)
|-- indexedFeatures: vector (nullable = true)
|-- prediction: double (nullable = true)

predict.show(5)
```

Leading into this error:

```
    17/09/16 19:12:25 WARN Utils: Truncated the string representation of a plan since it was too large. This behavior can be adjusted by setting 'spark.debug.maxToStringFields' in SparkEnv.conf.
Traceback (most recent call last):                                              
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 287, in show
    print(self._jdf.showString(n, truncate))
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/py4j-0.10.3-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/py4j-0.10.3-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o235.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$11: (vector) => vector)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply5_1$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.TakeOrderedAndProjectExec$$anonfun$executeCollect$1.apply(limit.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.TakeOrderedAndProjectExec$$anonfun$executeCollect$1.apply(limit.scala:132)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at 

scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.TakeOrderedAndProjectExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2193)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withNewExecutionId(Dataset.scala:2546)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1(Dataset.scala:2192)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collect(Dataset.scala:2199)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:1935)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:1934)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withTypedCallback(Dataset.scala:2576)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:1934)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2149)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:239)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:237)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: 1.0
    at scala.collection.MapLike$class.default(MapLike.scala:228)
    at scala.collection.AbstractMap.default(Map.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.MapLike$class.apply(MapLike.scala:141)
    at scala.collection.AbstractMap.apply(Map.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorIndexerModel$$anonfun$10.apply(VectorIndexer.scala:339)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorIndexerModel$$anonfun$10.apply(VectorIndexer.scala:317)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorIndexerModel$$anonfun$11.apply(VectorIndexer.scala:362)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorIndexerModel$$anonfun$11.apply(VectorIndexer.scala:362)
    ... 33 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because `PipelineModel` includes `VectorIndexerModel` and `features` contain unseen levels in one of the columns marked as categorical. You can easily reproduce the same error as follows:

```
val train = Seq((1L, Vectors.dense(0.0))).toDF("id", "foo")
val test = Seq((1L, Vectors.dense(1.0))).toDF("id", "foo")

new VectorIndexer().setInputCol("foo").setOutputCol("bar")
  .fit(train).transform(test).first
```

As of today `VectorIndexer` (Spark 2.2) Spark doesn't support handling unseen levels in `VectorIndexer` ([as it does with `StringIndexer`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35224675/1560062)) but this functionality [is planned for the future](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.2.0/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/feature/VectorIndexer.scala#L94).

**Edit**:

In Spark 2.3 you can use `handleInvalid`, for example:

```
new VectorIndexer()
  .setInputCol("foo").setOutputCol("bar")
  .setHandleInvalid("keep")
 .fit(train).transform(test).first
```

Comment: I have removed all the indexer attributes only basic types were there in my dataset even then I get the same error

Comment: is there a way to overcome this with sparak 2.2 because i believe a non indexed inputs aren't gonna be much effectives. @Alper