# pyspark: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$11: (vector) => vector)

Tags: apache-spark-sql

both of the train data and the test data have 52 features ,,have the same dimension. The way of extracting features are the same. The program has no syntax errors. When I added a random sampling of negative samples, the error occurred.

```html
17/10/02 10:28:23 ERROR HiveMetaStore: Failed to delete table directory: file:/E:/tianchi_taobao/tianchi2/spark-warehouse/re Got exception: org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.MetaException Unable to delete directory: file:/E:/tianchi_taobao/tianchi2/spark-warehouse/re
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/tianchi_taobao/tianchi2/test4.py", line 256, in <module>
    spark.sql("create table re as SELECT user_id,item_id FROM result WHERE prediction>0 ")
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\context.py", line 360, in sql
    return self.sparkSession.sql(sqlQuery)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\session.py", line 543, in sql
    return DataFrame(self._jsparkSession.sql(sqlQuery), self._wrapped)
  File "D:\spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.3-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "D:\spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.3-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o24.sql.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 4 in stage 25.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 4.0 in stage 25.0 (TID 3881, localhost): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$11: (vector) => vector)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:370)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.foreach(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:368)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.SparkHiveWriterContainer.writeToFile(hiveWriterContainers.scala:185)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.InsertIntoHiveTable$$anonfun$saveAsHiveFile$3.apply(InsertIntoHiveTable.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.InsertIntoHiveTable$$anonfun$saveAsHiveFile$3.apply(InsertIntoHiveTable.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: 0.006578947368421052
    at scala.collection.MapLike$class.default(MapLike.scala:228)
    at scala.collection.AbstractMap.default(Map.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.MapLike$class.apply(MapLike.scala:141)
    at scala.collection.AbstractMap.apply(Map.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorIndexerModel$$anonfun$10$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(VectorIndexer.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorIndexerModel$$anonfun$10$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(VectorIndexer.scala:323)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map2.foreach(Map.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorIndexerModel$$anonfun$10.apply(VectorIndexer.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorIndexerModel$$anonfun$10.apply(VectorIndexer.scala:317)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorIndexerModel$$anonfun$11.apply(VectorIndexer.scala:362)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorIndexerModel$$anonfun$11.apply(VectorIndexer.scala:362)
    ... 14 more
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know in details your features so I will assume that you have 52 separate columns and that your are using a `VectorAssemlber` to merge them.

First of all, check that you can assemble all of your features. If you have vectors and primitive features, you can't merge them.

Then check if you have some Indexer (`StringIndexer` or `VectorIndexer`) between your features. If positive, pay attention that in the training and test sets all the possible cases are available: maybe you have positive/negative labels only in the test set.

This question could potentially be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46257990/1419058) answer.

Comment: thanks, there are some detail I ignored.I have fixed it.

Comment: *`If positive, pay attention that in the training and test sets all the possible cases are available`* For anyone reading, this is important. For categorical variables, no classifier can be used to predict categories that exist in your test dataset, that it has not seen in your test dataset. If this is the case, you are likely to encounter issues when trying to run `model.transform(test)` after training your model on your train dataset.