# Sparklyr Error: Job aborted due to stage failure 22.0 failed 1 times, recent failure: Lost task SparkException: Unseen label

Tags: r, apache-spark, apache-spark-ml, sparklyr

I am tying to implement machine learning (kmeans) from my spark source. I have one table with 2 columns: review and label (positive or negative) Everything seems to work good. But when I run the prediction  I am getting the next error:

> SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 22.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 22.0 (TID 22, localhost): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Unseen label

Here is the code:

```
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local", version="2.0.0")

colnames(dfAllReviews3Cols) = c("ReviewText", "LabelReview")

#db_drop_table(sc, "dfallreviews3cols")
reviewsTbl <- copy_to(sc, dfAllReviews3Cols)

#List tables
src_tbls(sc)

#Select preview
reviews_preview <- dbGetQuery(sc, "SELECT * FROM dfallreviews3cols LIMIT 10")


##KMeans
partitions <- reviewsTbl %>%
  sdf_partition(training = 0.7, test = 0.3, seed = 999)

reviewsTbl_training <- partitions$training
reviewTbl_test <- partitions$test

kmeans_model <- reviewsTbl_training %>%
  ml_kmeans(ReviewText ~ .)

pred <- sdf_predict(reviewTbl_test, kmeans_model) %>% collect
```

This is the error I got:

> pred <- sdf_predict(reviewTbl_test, kmeans_model) %>% collect
>   Error: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 22.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 22.0 (TID 22, localhost): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Unseen label:  AC wasn t working in my room When the repair man came to fix it he couldn't and then told me that it s winter and people don t need the AC Room was uncomfortably hot Check out was a nightmare My cab driver was waiting to take me to the airport Twice reception told me I had money to be owed however this was untrue after they checked their records I had the same problem at check in Bell boy took over 20 min to bring my bags down from my room wouldn't recommend this hotel .
>
> at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexerModel$$anonfun$4.apply(StringIndexer.scala:169)
>   at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexerModel$$anonfun$4.apply(StringIndexer.scala:165)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:370)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkPlan.scala:246)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkPlan.scala:240)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:784)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:784)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
>           at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

```
Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1450)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1438)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1437)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1437)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1659)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1618)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1607)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:632)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1871)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1884)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1897)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1911)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:893)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:358)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:892)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.scala:290)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2183)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withNewExecutionId(Dataset.scala:2532)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1(Dataset.scala:2182)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collect$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2187)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collect$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2187)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withCallback(Dataset.scala:2545)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collect(Dataset.scala:2187)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collect(Dataset.scala:2163)
    at sparklyr.Utils$.collect(utils.scala:200)
    at sparklyr.Utils.collect(utils.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at sparklyr.Invoke.invoke(invoke.scala:139)
    at sparklyr.StreamHandler.handleMethodCall(stream.scala:123)
    at sparklyr.StreamHandler.read(stream.scala:66)
    at sparklyr.BackendHandler.channelRead0(handler.scala:51)
    at sparklyr.BackendHandler.channelRead0(handler.scala:4)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:244)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:846)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Unseen label:  AC wasn t working in my room When the repair man came to fix it he couldn t and then told me that it s winter and people don t need the AC Room was uncomfortably hot Check out was a nightmare My cab driver was waiting to take me to the airport Twice reception told me I had money to be owed however this was untrue after they checked their records I had the same problem at check in Bell boy took over 20 min to bring my bags down from my room Wouldn t recommend this hotel .
    at org.apache
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks inadvance!

Answer (score 2):

That's really not the way to go. Based on the error message, `ReviewText` is clearly a block of unstructured text.

If you pass it directly to `ml_kmeans` it will be treated as a categorical variable, passed through [`StringIndexer`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#stringindexer) (this is where the failure occurs - if you're interested in details you can check [spark.ml StringIndexer throws 'Unseen label' on fit()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35224675/6910411), but in practice, it is hardly relevant here). Then the result will assembled into a vector of length equal to 1.

As you can imagine that's not a very useful model.

In general you should *at least* (this might not, and likely won't be, enough to achieve good results in practice):

- Tokenize the raw text.
- Encode the tokens.

Spark ML provides a small set of basic text transformers, including, but not limited to, [`Tokenizer`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#tokenizer), [`StopWordsRemover`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#stopwordsremover), [`NGram`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#n-gram), [TF-IDF](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#tf-idf), and additional, more advanced tools are provided by 3rd party libraries (most notably [John Snow Labs’ NLP](https://nlp.johnsnowlabs.com/) ), as well as [`Pipeline` API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-pipeline.html), which can be used [to compose these, into reusable modules](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50534224/6910411). I strongly encourage you to read the official documentation of each of these tools before you proceed.

Going back to your problem you can start with something like this

```
pipeline <- ml_pipeline(
  # Tokenize the input
  ft_tokenizer(sc, input_col = "ReviewText", output_col = "raw_tokens"),

  # Remove stopwords - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_words
  ft_stop_words_remover(sc, input_col = "raw_tokens", output_col = "tokens"),

  # Apply TF-IDF - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf-idf
  ft_hashing_tf(sc, input_col = "tokens", output_col = "tfs"),
  ft_idf(sc, input_col = "tfs", output_col = "features"),
  ml_kmeans(sc, features_col = "features", init_mode = "random")
)

model <- ml_fit(pipeline, reviewsTbl_training)
```

and adjust it to fit your particular scenario.